# VSE: sound animations lost in scene strips

Tags: video-sequence-editor, scene, audio

In my first large video editing project, I make my life easier by splitting the total video into a number of scenes, and merging them together in a main scene.

What I have so far, is this:

- Scene 1, which contains several VSE-strips with video and sound.
- Scene 2, which contains more VSE-strips with video and sound.
- The main scene, which contains 2 VSE-strips of type "scene", that link the data of scene 1 and 2.

When I render the video, all the sounds and images of scene 1 and 2 are present in the final result, but I have one problem: all the animation I did on sound strips is gone.

Whenever there's a voice-over in scene 1 or 2, I turn down the volume of the background music to prevent the music from drowning out the voice-over.
This works fine if I render out scene 1 and 2 separately, but when I render the main scene, the volume differences of the sub-scenes are gone: all sounds just keep playing at 100% of their original volume.

Is this a bug in Blender, or am I missing some setting that can fix this issue?